# Two JSF libraries providing the same renderer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

**Short Version**:

If two JSF library jar files both include a custom renderer for the same family and type, is there any way from within the library itself (i.e. not from the containing app) of specifying which one should be used? Something like assigning a priority, with higher ones used in preference to lower ones?

**Longer Version**:

I'm using Primefaces in a project and trying to override the provided head renderer with my own:

```
<render-kit>
  <renderer>
    <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
    <renderer-type>javax.faces.Head</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>com.example.MyHeadRenderer</renderer-class>
  </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

If I put that into the `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` of the war file then it's all good, and my renderer gets used.

However, if I try to deploy my code as part of a library jar (my-utils.jar), with the renderer defined in `META-INF/faces-config.xml`, then the Primefaces one is used. This contains exactly the same definition, so I'm guessing it just depends on the order they get loaded. Indeed, renaming my library to "xx-comps.jar" works, so it would appear that JSF is loading `faces-config.xml` files from all jar files in alphabetical order, with later entries just overwriting earlier ones.

Is there any way of forcing the selection to my library?

So far, I have these options:

1. Put my renderer directly into the `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` of the war.
2. Build a custom Primefaces jar with that one renderer definition
   removed.
3. Rename my library and rely on some (undocumented as far as I can
   see) behaviour from the JSF loader.
4. Add a custom renderkit which extends the standard one, and reference
   that from my war `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml`.

The first three all work but are not ideal, as (1) and (2) require changes outside my library, and (3) just looks dodgy as hell....

The fourth is just an idea as I've never written a render kit before so not aware of the effort involved. No idea if it is practical or would work, but it is better than (1) because at least the application only references a single render kit, and does not need to be updated if/when new renderers are added. Happy to put more effort into researching this approach if it seems a reasonable solution.

Also, I'd ideally prefer to use annotations rather than XML:

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily = "javax.faces.Output", rendererType = "javax.faces.Head")
public class MyHeadRenderer extends Renderer {
  ...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the ordering via `<ordering>` in `faces-config.xml` of the JAR.

E.g. if you want your utility library to be loaded after all others, then just do so:

```
<ordering>
    <after>
        <others />
    </after>
</ordering>
```

If you want to force an explicit ordering, then hook on specifically PrimeFaces, which has a `<name>primefaces</name>` in its `faces-config.xml`:

```
<ordering>
    <after>
        <name>primefaces</name>
    </after>
</ordering>
```

Comment: Only works for the `faces-config.xml` approach, but solves my problem in a simple way so thanks for that. I'm guessing the annotation is clobbered by section 11.5.1 of the spec as a "_conflict between an entry in the Application Configuration Resources and an annotation_", which seems wrong to me as I would say that with an ordering there is no conflict, but I guess that is a matter of interpretation.